# Beginner question - I only know python, how do I use an API?

Tags: python, php, json, api

I'm trying to use a website's API and I am completely lost, I only know python and I have no idea how to phrase this code in python or what programs I should run this one, I also need to be able to easily give this code to other people without them installing a lot of new programs on their computer just it would run. Any idea what I should do?

This is from the documentation:

```
#!/bin/bash
clientId=“my_client_id”
secret=“my_secret”
curl -H “AuthClientId: ${clientId}” -H “AuthSecret: ${secret}”
“https://…”

<?php 

$clientId='my_client_id'; 
$secret='my_secret'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https:...."); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "AuthClientId: {$clientId}", "AuthSecret: {$secret}" )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$body = curl_exec($ch); 
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); curl_close($ch); 

?>

#!/bin/env powershell

$clientId = ‘my_client_id’
$secret = ‘my_secret’

$url = “https…”

$headers = @{
  “AuthClientId” = $clientId;
  “AuthSecret” = $secret;
}

try {
  $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method GET
  Write-Output $result
}
catch {
  $errorvalue = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
  Write-Output “Got Error $errorvalue”
}
```

This is the python code I tried so far but it returned a 405 error:

```
import requests
API_KEY = 'API KEY'
headerss = {
    'clientId': 'clientId'
}

payload = {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
}

r = requests.get("https://console.clubvps.com/service/authenticate", headers = headerss, params = payload)

print (r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

after inspecting your url, it says `Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST`

so try

`r = requests.post("https://console.clubvps.com/service/authenticate", headers = headerss, params = payload)`

more explanation of http methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: Getting a 400 error now, not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: It probably is your headers config, but since I don't have your credential, it is hard for me to tell

Comment: I have no idea why they wouldn't work, I copied them directly from the documentation. If I wanted to try the code on another program, what are the other programs the code I posted above uses?

Comment: you can test your credential and headers using Postman. It is an API testing software that is popular among web developers.

Comment: Thanks!

I looked at the documentation and found this, could this be causing an error?

"All connections to the API must use Transport Layer Security (TLS)"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured out why it didn't work, I should have been sending the authentication keys and password as "data". This is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
API_KEY = '...'
CLIENT_ID = '...'


data = {
    'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
    'secret': API_KEY
}



r = requests.post("https://console.clubvps.com/service/authenticate" , data=data)

print (r.status_code)
```